# Solspace Freeform Upload file dynamic location and duplicate file avoidance

Tags: assets, upload, plugin-freeform, solspace

Using Freeform for forms which have multiple file upload fields.

Is it possible to have a unique asset directory for each submission? For example: uploads/maindirectory/*submission.id*/ I'm trying to make it easier for the website admins to see all of the uploaded files in one location, **but mainly** to prevent multiple users uploading files of the same filename.

Users are requested to upload scanned documents, so file names such as "scan1.jpg", "scan2.jpg" could be a common theme and would not work in this case as craft natively doesn't allow the same file uploaded twice meaning freeform throws a validation error.